# OneSignal Push for array of vales

Tags: ios, push-notification, onesignal, parse-cloud-code

Using Parse Cloud to send push notifications with OneSignal.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('push', function(request, response) {
  var user = request.params.userId;
  var message = request.params.message;
  var type = request.params.type;

  var jsonBody = {
      app_id: "9c618b01-e43d-4a9e-b54e-14f1162dc3c4",
      tags: [{"key": "userId", "relation": "=", "value": user}],
      contents: {en: message},
      data: {"type":type}
  };
```

This is how I send a push to a single user. But I need to send a push notification to multiple people at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

To deliver notifications to users who have one of several tags, you can specify multiple tags with the OR operator.

Here is an example of how your code could be modified to do this:

```
  Parse.Cloud.define('push', function(request, response) {
  var user1 = request.params.userId1;
  var user2 = request.params.userId2;
  var user3 = request.params.userId3;
  var message = request.params.message;
  var type = request.params.type;

  var jsonBody = {
      app_id: "9c618b01-e43d-4a9e-b54e-14f1162dc3c4",
      tags: [{"key": "userId", "relation": "=", "value": user1},{"operator": "OR"},{"key": "userId", "relation": "=", "value": user2},{"operator": "OR"},{"key": "userId", "relation": "=", "value": user2}],
      contents: {en: message},
      data: {"type":type}
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I will not know the number of subscribed users. So should I send up an array and loop through then send a push to each individual using a = relation?